# Bootstrap Slider in Django is not working

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>

<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
```

```
<div class="item active ">

  <img src="{% static 'imgs/pic1.jpg' %}" alt="Bank1">

</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="{% static 'imgs/pic2.jpg' %}" alt="Bank2">

</div>

<div class="item">

  <img src="{% static 'imgs/pic3.jpg' %}" alt="Bank3">

</div>
```

Slider does not work it shows only pics, I want slider I'm using Django framework. 
I just made this bootstrap slider and it's perfect but in my scenario, it's not working it just shows me pictures which I included in the slider, but slider not working  !!!

Comment: Can you share the slider markup? That's only three divs with images, which will only ever show those images.

Comment: This is my total code that i made till now , i am just using it for web application which is based on banking system.
I am only able to make that code for slider if you know how to make it or you can correct it so please help!

Comment: It won't help to do the work for you. You should look into the [Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/) component and the [range input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range). Those will help get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

This should ideally for work you. You must place the images in an appropriate Bootstrap class for images to be seen in the slider.

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'imgs/pic1.jpg' %}" alt="First slide">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'imgs/pic2.jpg' %}" alt="Second slide">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'imgs/pic3.jpg' %}" alt="Third slide">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but with bootstrap classes.